# get value from my SelectListItem so it can get into the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm close to throw my content into the database, but when I try to get it into the database so that it can in no way allow themselves to do to get it into.

problems that are not getting value into the database while writing this here error.

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

**Post here**

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult create(AccountViewModels userindhold)
    {
        DataLinqDB db = new DataLinqDB();
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var username = db.brugeres.FirstOrDefault(i => i.brugernavn == userindhold.Brugernavn);
            if (username == null)
            {
                brugere OpretUser = new brugere();
                OpretUser.kon = Convert.ToInt32(userindhold.Kon);//error her
                OpretUser.birthday = Convert.ToDateTime(userindhold.Birthday);//error her
                OpretUser.nyhedsbrevKategori_Id = Convert.ToInt32(userindhold.KategoriNyhedsbrev);//error her

                db.brugeres.InsertOnSubmit(OpretUser);

                db.SubmitChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("login");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Denne e-mail er genkendelig.");
            }

        }
        return View();
    }
```

**Get**

```
[HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult create()
    {
        DataLinqDB db = new DataLinqDB();

        AccountViewModels ac = new AccountViewModels();

        ViewBag.Kon = new SelectList(db.Kons, "id", "konvalue");
        ViewBag.KategoriNyhedsbrev = new SelectList(db.KategoriNyhedsbrevs, "id", "tekst");

        return View();
    }
```

**Modelse here**

```
[Display(Name = "Hvilken kategori kan du li til nyhedsbrevet?")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> KategoriNyhedsbrev
    {
        get; set;
    }

    [Display(Name = "Hvilke køn er du?")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Kon
    {
        get; set;
    }
```

**I have a form around these here and there are more input area.**

index.cshtml

```
<div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                @Html.LabelFor(u => u.Kon)
                @Html.DropDownList("Kon", null, new
           {
               @class = "form-control",
           })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                @Html.LabelFor(u => u.KategoriNyhedsbrev)
                @Html.DropDownList("KategoriNyhedsbrev", null, new
           {
               @class = "form-control",
           })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your AccountViewModel, `Kon` is a property of type `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and you are trying to pass that into `Convert.ToInt32` method. The [Convert.ToInt32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.toint32(v=vs.110).aspx) usually expects a string version of your numeric data ( Ex : `"34"`) so that it can be safely converted to it's integer version (Ex : `34`). There is no way this method can convert a list to an integer value.

What you should be ideally doing is add a property to your view model to hold the selected item value

```
public class AccountViewModel
{
  public int SelectedKon {set;get;}
  public List<SelectListItem> Kon { get; set; }

  //Your other properties also goes here
}
```

And in your razor view,

```
@model AccountViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.DropDownListFor(s=>s.SelectedKon, Model.Kon,"Select one item")
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

Now in your HttpPost action, You can use `SelectedKon` property value of the posted model

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(AccountViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      brugere OpretUser = new brugere();
      OpretUser.kon = model.SelectedKon;
      //Do other useful things and redirect to a Success page.
    }
    //TO DO : Reload the model.Kon collection again here.
    return View(model)
}
```

You should do the same for all your dropdowns.

Comment: Thanks for the good description. but it shows errors here. `s => s.SelectedKon`

Comment: Did you add that property to your view model ?

Comment: I add it to the view I have taken a picture as you can see here. http://postimg.org/image/yepf5dahx/

Comment: You are using the wrong helper method. Use `DropDownListFor` as i posted in my answer.

Comment: ohh sorry. i have dont see its.

Comment: Are you passing in a 
**NON NULL** object to the view from your action method ?

Comment: Before you help me I got something out of the database. but just do not throw it into the database or take it on.